# Adding importrange to index match formula where the import range is required in both index and match

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, match, vlookup

I have this formula for import range that works when within the same workbook but I now need to include importrange within the ranges that sit in both index and match.

```
=iferror(INDEX(HS_Master!D:D,match(H2,HS_Master!C:C,)))
```

The sheet reference is correct but I am not sure where the importrange & URL needs to go before index D:D and match C:C

I do not have an example sheet to share as yet but I will work on one

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(H2, IMPORTRANGE("url", "HS_Master!C:D"), 2, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using this vlookup before but I was told that it could be the reason my sheets keep freezing. I heard index match processes faster but I don’t know

Comment: @Stuart wherever you use importrange within VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH it is the same. remember: the culprit is IMPORTRANGE - especially when dataset is huge. btw, I hope you are not using same formula in H3 & downwards... in that case its an overkill for sure. use this in row 2 only: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H2:H, IMPORTRANGE("url", "HS_Master!C:D"), 2, 0)))`

Comment: another super impressive formula. Thank you  